# Compiled .jar file not working properly

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-library, mopub

Now the long explanation, I have a library project (MoPub SDK), which I need to have it as a .jar file.

If I try to include this library project into my actual Androi project, it works just fine, but if I right click on the library Export>Java>Jar, and with these options for example (tried a few combinations, still the same), it does not work fine, its full of warnings, and does not serve ads.

[image]

[Screenshot 2](http://s29.postimg.org/nfbim8rjr/image.png)

[Screenshot 3](http://s14.postimg.org/wb69ppfi9/image.png)

Since it works fine when included as a library project, I guess it has something to do with the Exporting. What could be wrong?

EDIT: And here are the warnings

```
    06-16 07:12:01.090: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.090: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.294: D/dalvikvm(15409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 926K, 13% free 6785K/7780K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
06-16 07:12:01.302: I/Ads(15409): Trying mediation network: 10872986198578383917
06-16 07:12:01.302: I/Ads(15409): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter
06-16 07:12:01.318: I/dalvikvm(15409): Failed resolving Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest$Listener; interface 7527 'Lcom/mopub/volley/Response$ErrorListener;'
06-16 07:12:01.318: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest$Listener;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.318: I/dalvikvm(15409): Failed resolving Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController$1; interface 7485 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest$Listener;'
06-16 07:12:01.318: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController$1;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.322: E/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find class 'com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1', referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.<init>
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 7194 (Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController$1;) in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;
06-16 07:12:01.322: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0031
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mopub/volley/VolleyError;)
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 19983
06-16 07:12:01.322: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0000
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.322: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.322: I/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find method com.mopub.network.AdRequest.cancel, referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.cleanup
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 51688: Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;.cancel ()V
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: E/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find class 'com.mopub.network.AdRequest', referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.fetchAd
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 7486 (Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;) in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0013
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mopub/volley/VolleyError;)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/MoPubNetworkError; (7532)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/MoPubNetworkError;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: E/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find class 'com.mopub.network.MoPubNetworkError', referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.onAdLoadError
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 7494 (Lcom/mopub/network/MoPubNetworkError;) in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0000
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/TrackingRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/TrackingRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find method com.mopub.network.TrackingRequest.makeTrackingHttpRequest, referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.registerClick
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve static method 51902: Lcom/mopub/network/TrackingRequest;.makeTrackingHttpRequest (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/mopub/common/event/BaseEvent$Name;)V
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000e
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find method com.mopub.network.AdRequest.isCanceled, referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.setNotLoading
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 51696: Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;.isCanceled ()Z
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/TrackingRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/TrackingRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): Could not find method com.mopub.network.TrackingRequest.makeTrackingHttpRequest, referenced from method com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.trackImpression
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: unable to resolve static method 51902: Lcom/mopub/network/TrackingRequest;.makeTrackingHttpRequest (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/mopub/common/event/BaseEvent$Name;)V
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000e
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): Failed resolving Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest$Listener; interface 7527 'Lcom/mopub/volley/Response$ErrorListener;'
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest$Listener;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): Failed resolving Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController$1; interface 7485 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest$Listener;'
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController$1;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xc1ea at 0x33 in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;.<init>
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x4e0f at 0x30 in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;.getErrorCodeFromVolleyError
06-16 07:12:01.326: I/dalvikvm(15409): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x4e0e at 0x32 in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;.getErrorCodeFromVolleyError
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest; (7524)
06-16 07:12:01.326: W/dalvikvm(15409): Link of class 'Lcom/mopub/network/AdRequest;' failed
06-16 07:12:01.326: D/dalvikvm(15409): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xc9e7 at 0x20 in Lcom/mopub/mobileads/AdViewController;.fetchAd
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409): Could not request interstitial ad from adapter.
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.<init>(AdViewController.java:112)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.factories.AdViewControllerFactory.internalCreate(AdViewControllerFactory.java:21)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.factories.AdViewControllerFactory.create(AdViewControllerFactory.java:17)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:84)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:58)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial$MoPubInterstitialView.<init>(MoPubInterstitial.java:251)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubInterstitial.<init>(MoPubInterstitial.java:57)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter.requestInterstitialAd(MoPubAdapter.java:115)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter.requestInterstitialAd(MoPubAdapter.java:1)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb$1.run(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409): Could not request ad from mediation adapter.
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409): android.os.RemoteException
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb$1.run(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-16 07:12:01.330: W/Ads(15409):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.334: I/Ads(15409): Trying mediation network: 5450213213286189855
06-16 07:12:01.346: I/Ads(15409): Trying mediation network: 10872986198578383917
06-16 07:12:01.346: I/Ads(15409): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter
06-16 07:12:01.346: W/Ads(15409): Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-5277082322505112\/4764792985\/qdata=AJ5UM1lACOTjxfXmBwQaqQ6GSHR3SJzjnoYWVny3fYzOjes7-1zrvELSrxj_aH8uL62jlNLXss_78598mgSAVKORhiRnomKY3oFULNvSnd8-iX-YFQ&allocation_ids=3772237938885119"}
06-16 07:12:01.346: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(15409): Google Play services is missing.
06-16 07:12:01.346: W/Ads(15409): Using InterstitialAdManager from the client jar.
06-16 07:12:01.350: I/Ads(15409): Starting ad request.
06-16 07:12:01.354: I/Ads(15409): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("173230171DD16042118D1A86C149DC58") to get test ads on this device.
06-16 07:12:01.378: I/Ads(15409): CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
06-16 07:12:01.402: I/Ads(15409): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409): Could not request banner ad from adapter.
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController.<init>(AdViewController.java:112)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.factories.AdViewControllerFactory.internalCreate(AdViewControllerFactory.java:21)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.factories.AdViewControllerFactory.create(AdViewControllerFactory.java:17)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:84)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.<init>(MoPubView.java:58)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter.requestBannerAd(MoPubAdapter.java:91)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter.requestBannerAd(MoPubAdapter.java:1)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb$1.run(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-16 07:12:01.410: W/Ads(15409):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409): Could not request ad from mediation adapter.
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409): android.os.RemoteException
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb.zza(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeb$1.run(Unknown Source)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-16 07:12:01.414: W/Ads(15409):       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 07:12:01.414: I/Ads(15409): Trying mediation network: 5450213213286189855
06-16 07:12:01.418: I/Ads(15409): Instantiating mediation adapter: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter
06-16 07:12:01.418: W/Ads(15409): Server parameters: {"gwhirl_share_location":"1","pubid":"ca-app-pub-5277082322505112\/8521961786\/qdata=AJ5UM1kNuaGe_3VdNnfjxZnsQ1cD35swzy7yPP3PdnpALBvwMwxjrk80guXjmUhcNg9S2-y7W6TCLmpEQAgtf3kzvlWy8jsteiC-UJLI6rUXFZ0laA&allocation_ids=4433792869532879"}
06-16 07:12:01.418: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(15409): Google Play services is missing.
06-16 07:12:01.422: I/Ads(15409): Starting ad request.
06-16 07:12:01.422: I/Ads(15409): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("173230171DD16042118D1A86C149DC58") to get test ads on this device.
06-16 07:12:01.438: I/Ads(15409): CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
06-16 07:12:01.454: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.454: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.502: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.562: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.562: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.562: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.594: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.594: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:01.990: D/dalvikvm(15409): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 931K, 13% free 6941K/7944K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
06-16 07:12:02.022: W/EGL_genymotion(15409): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-16 07:12:02.038: W/AwContents(15409): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
06-16 07:12:02.418: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-16 07:12:02.450: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-16 07:12:02.662: I/Ads(15409): Ad finished loading.
06-16 07:12:02.670: I/Ads(15409): Ad finished loading.
06-16 07:12:02.682: I/Ads(15409): Ad finished loading.
06-16 07:12:02.682: I/Ads(15409): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-16 07:12:02.690: I/Ads(15409): Ad finished loading.
06-16 07:12:02.766: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-16 07:12:03.117: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:03.117: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
06-16 07:12:03.117: I/chromium(15409): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
```

EDIT 2: This is what the library looks like:
[image]

Comment: It is full of what warnings and errors? How do you use the generated JAR?

Comment: sorry, only warnings

Comment: What do you mean by "how do you use the generated jar"? I Include it in my project in the Java Build Path libraries, if thats what you are asking

Comment: Java Build Path means the project is built against the JAR but not linked with it during Dexing (converting to Dalvik's format). You need to put it in the `libs` directory instead.

Comment: just tried it, getting the same warnings :/

Comment: Do you see that the JAR in Java Build Path is used from `libs`?

Comment: Here - http://s12.postimg.org/p8a26dg7x/Capture.png

Comment: if you export JAR from library you need to include it in ur classpath, and CHECK export option in next Tab, also this may miss some resources, as a library project may use some images/strings/layouts from /res folder, those will not be included when you export Library project as JAR

Comment: nope. see my question again please, I edited it with a picture of the library, that I need to compile into a jar

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the game and i am using a custom jar file for mopub. Which includes mopub SDK and some extra flair from my company. I was getting a similar error specifically

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29142): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mopub.mobileads.AdViewController$1
```

I was able to resolve it by adding this file mopub-volley-1.0.0.jar to my libs folder. Its a NoClassDefFoundError which means that some files are avialable during compiling but not available during run-time. Try adding the volley-1.0.0.jar and that should resolve this issue.

Comment: as you can see from the screenshot, the volley jar is already there

Comment: hmm... try moving your mopub.jar to your /libs folder and add it to the build path as well and try building it.